# parseInt returns number on F, without second argument

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pretty simple, but I cannot understand why this is happening, if this isn't normal behavior, I assume it must be a bugg in my code, but since I checked everything and it seems to be right, I think it must be something parseInt is doing.

My code:

```
$(array).each(function(key, value){
    //ignore the if statement, it's about the else if statement
    if (isNaN(value) && poppin === 'h') {
        console.log(reverseArray);
    } else if (typeof parseInt(value) === 'number') {
            console.log(value);
            numbers++;
    } else {
        console.log('this else statement is pretty useless');
    }
});
```

now, if the array were to be:

```
let array = ['f', '1', '2', '3'];
```

it'll end up in the `else if` statement, even though (I assume) F is not a number. I read about `parseInt()` and if I give the second parameter an argument it could (and would) calculate F to a number such as: `parseInt('F', 16);`

My question: Why is `f` considered an integer in the context of my code?

Comment: The value `NaN` is a number.

Comment: So it returns NaN when it encounters the letter f, but it considers f a number?

Comment: Why don't you just type `parseInt("f");`, look at the result, then type `typeof NaN;`, look at the result? That should get you a lot further than you were previously?

Comment: Well, I did not think of that. I was just baffled at the fact that it kept on handling the value f as a number.

Comment: Also, i assume that `poppin === 'h'` is false? Because `isNaN("f") === true;`.

Comment: what is `reverseArray`?

Comment: Yes, `NaN` is a number that has special behavior.

Answer (score 0):

F is a hexadecimal. 
The second parameter is the type of sequence of numbers. For example, `parseInt(5, 2);` will return `101` because its returns the number in binary (2 numbers, 1 and 0). The second argument can be 2 (Binary), 8 (Octal) and 16 (Hexadecimal). The reason your `parseInt('F', 16);` returns a number is because there is 16 numbers in that sequence (or 10 numbers, 0-9 and 5 letters representing numbers.`A = 10, B = 11, C = 12, D = 13, E = 14, F = 15`).

```js
var number = 'F';
console.log(parseInt(number, 2)); // F isn't part of sequence (0,1)
console.log(parseInt(number, 8)); // F isn't part of sequence (0-7)
console.log(parseInt(number, 16)); // F is 15, as defined in answer
```

Therefore, `F` is not considered a number in any other set apart from `16`. And the typeOf which returns NaN is not equal to number. Therefore, it should run perfectly if the condition `poppin === 'h'` was removed (Thats where your problem is).

```js
var nums = ['F', 20];
for (n of nums) {

  // Your code being run with two different values
  if (isNaN(n)) {
          console.log("Not a number");
   } else if (typeof parseInt(n) === 'number') {
          console.log("A number");
   }
   
}
```